# How to sort an array by frequency of occurrence?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I've array like this :

```
people = [
{id:1,name:'abc',age:18},
{id:2,name:'abcd',age:20},
{id:3,name:'abce',age:18},
{id:4,name:'abcf',age:18},
{id:5,name:'abcg',age:21},
{id:6,name:'abch',age:20},
{id:7,name:'abci',age:17},
]
```

Now I want Sorting an array order by frequency of occurence(age) in JavaScript.
Output like this:

```
people = [
{id:1,name:'abc',age:18},
{id:3,name:'abce',age:18},
{id:4,name:'abcf',age:18},
{id:2,name:'abcd',age:20},
{id:6,name:'abch',age:20},
{id:5,name:'abcg',age:21},
{id:7,name:'abci',age:17},
]
```

So how I can do it ?

I've tried follow answer of Nina Scholz but i've a bug like this.

```
var people = [{ id: 1, name: 'abc', age: 18 }, { id: 2, name: 'abcd', age: 20 }, { id: 3, name: 'abce', age: 18 }, { id: 4, name: 'abcf', age: 18 }, { id: 5, name: 'abcg', age: 21 }, { id: 6, name: 'abch', age: 20 }, { id: 7, name: 'abcg', age: 21 }, { id: 8, name: 'abci', age: 17 }],
count = people.reduce((r, { age }) => (r[age] = (r[age] || 0) + 1, r), {});

people.sort((a, b) => count[b.age] - count[a.age]);

console.log(people);
```

Output is :

```
people = [
{id:1,name:'abc',age:18},
{id:3,name:'abce',age:18},
{id:4,name:'abcf',age:18},
{id:2,name:'abcd',age:20},
{id:5,name:'abcg',age:21},
{id:6,name:'abch',age:20},
{id:5,name:'abcg',age:21},
{id:7,name:'abci',age:17},
]
```

Comment: Count the frequency for each age, then sort by it.

Answer (score 5):

Just count ages and sort descending by the count.

```js
var people = [{ id: 1, name: 'abc', age: 18 }, { id: 2, name: 'abcd', age: 20 }, { id: 3, name: 'abce', age: 18 }, { id: 4, name: 'abcf', age: 18 }, { id: 5, name: 'abcg', age: 21 }, { id: 6, name: 'abch', age: 20 }, { id: 7, name: 'abci', age: 17 }],
    count = people.reduce((r, { age }) => (r[age] = (r[age] || 0) + 1, r), {});

people.sort((a, b) => count[b.age] - count[a.age]);

console.log(people);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For sorting by `count` **and** `age`, add a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) along with the delta of the ages.

```js
   var people = [{ id: 1, name: 'abc', age: 18 }, { id: 2, name: 'abcd', age: 20 }, { id: 3, name: 'abce', age: 18 }, { id: 4, name: 'abcf', age: 18 }, { id: 5, name: 'abcg', age: 21 }, { id: 6, name: 'abch', age: 20 }, { id: 7, name: 'abcg', age: 21 }, { id: 8, name: 'abci', age: 17 }],
    count = people.reduce((r, { age }) => (r[age] = (r[age] || 0) + 1, r), {});

people.sort((a, b) =>
    count[b.age] - count[a.age] ||
    b.age - a.age
);

console.log(people);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Won't this execute `reduce` twice for each element in the array?

Comment: the reduce visits each element of the array only once.

Comment: @paul `count` is the result after `reduce` executes.

Comment: the sort reference the result of the reduce, it doesn't call it

Comment: tkank you for your comment

Comment: @ZemZem, please have a look to the edit, which covers now the order of same count.

Comment: @NinaScholz oh wow it's very clean . This means a lot to me bro !! . But i wonder if age is String , how to make it right ?

Comment: @ZemZem, as long as the value converts to a number, then there is no problem, because `-` converts both operands to numbers.

Comment: If anyone has issue on sort not working, just add return to the sort function value

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let people = [{ id: 1, name: 'abc', age: 18 }, { id: 2, name: 'abcd', age: 20 }, { id: 3, name: 'abce', age: 18 }, { id: 4, name: 'abcf', age: 18 }, { id: 5, name: 'abcg', age: 21 }, { id: 6, name: 'abch', age: 20 }, { id: 7, name: 'abci', age: 17 }];
let tmpAge = {};
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  if (!tmpAge[people[i].age]) {
    tmpAge[people[i].age] = 1;
  } else {
    tmpAge[people[i].age]++;
  }
}
people.sort((a, b) => tmpAge[b.age] - tmpAge[a.age]);
console.log(people);
```

Comment: yeah sure !! tkank you !!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const people = [
  { id: 1, name: 'abc', age: 18 },
  { id: 2, name: 'abcd', age: 20 },
  { id: 3, name: 'abce', age: 18 },
  { id: 4, name: 'abcf', age: 18 },
  { id: 5, name: 'abcg', age: 21 },
  { id: 6, name: 'abch', age: 20 },
  { id: 7, name: 'abci', age: 17 },
];

const agesFrequency = people.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  const { age } = currentValue;

  return {
    ...previousValue,
    [age]: (
      previousValue[age] || 0
    ) + 1,
  };
}, {});

people.sort((
  (a, b) =>
    agesFrequency[b.age] - agesFrequency[a.age]
));

console.log(people);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it . Change function sort to

```
people.sort((a, b) => {
    if (count[b.age] === count[a.age]) {
        if (b.age < a.age) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (b.age > a.age) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    } else if (count[b.age] < count[a.age]) {
        return -1;
    }
});
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of OP*</sub>